# Yii2 сайт на Apache+Nginx/OpenServer

Tags: apache, nginx, yii2

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь поставить [этот](https://github.com/trntv/yii2-starter-kit#installation) yii2 шаблон. Вроде как даже получилось, но нужно настроить виртуальные сервера на openserver apache+nginx. Я пытался но либо это не работало, либо сервер вообще не ключался. По умолчанию сайт доступен по адресу site.com/frontend/web, site.com/backend/web, site.com/storage/web. Мне нужно что бы при заходе на сайт X рутом становился => Y:

- site.com => site.com/frontend/web
- admin.site.com => site.com/backend/web
- storage.site.com => site.com/storage/web

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добрый день, 
 возможно Вы имеете настройку доменов для OpenServer.

В настройках OpenServer находим вкладку "Домены"
Выбираем Ручное+Автопоиск для "Управления доменами".

В имя домена вводите желаемое вами: "site.com", а папку домена выбираете именно ту, которую хотите привязать -> site.com/frontend/web.

Сохраняетесь, перезапускаете сервер и всё работает.